# Application Insights - System.Diagnostics.Trace.* - What are these used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to explain as much as possible with as little as possible in the title. But I've added Application Insights and enabled trace listening to a .Net web app during configuration and when doing this, some code is presented as shown in the screenshot below to log information from app during runtime under the Trace collection enabled.

[image: Configuring Application Insights]
I've been looking the three lines of code up and can't find them being used enough to learn what exactly the three lines of code are used for.

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Information"); 
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("Warning"); 
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Error");
```

I'm guessing these would be used like regular logging lines of code like `Log.Information` but I'm not positive and there's not much explanation from Microsoft. Or do we add these trace listeners at application startup and it traces logging any time there's a `Log.Information` or `Log.Error` etc...?

Any advice or direction on where I can learn more about this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not much explanation from MS?  There is a tremendous amount of documentation available on Tracing and Application Insights.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs

Comment: @Amy not much explanation in the above screenshot, do you see that? I even searched the lines of code and couldn't find specific documentation. I also searched System.Diagnostics.Trace. That's why I posted and asked for a professional who knows this exact stuff to point me in the direction to learn about this if there was any. Which is what you did more or less. Why am I wrong for that...?

Comment: You're wrong because you accused MS of not providing you with documentation when there is *ample* documentation available online.  Believe it or not, your screenshot is not the place an explanation belongs.

Comment: I said Microsoft didn't provide much of an explanation in the screenshot I was showing, that is all, and that is an accurate statement. That screenshot is absolutely where a "Learn More" link belongs. But now what we are talking about is subjective.

Comment: Next time, use Google to do your own research.  I'm glad I was able to do it for you this time.

Comment: I'm almost inclined to post every single search I did. You don't know me nor anything I've done prior to posting. So chill out. Don't help next time or ask the people in charge to reprimand me if you feel I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're right, I don't know you or what you did prior to coming here.  I'm judging your content *here*.  " Don't help next time or ask the people in charge to reprimand me"  That isn't how any of this works.

Comment: You have the option of asking about this on Meta.  You'll get the same answer though.  Next time, use Google to search for documentation *before* accusing a major corporation of not explaining anything.

Comment: Again, no much of an explanation is an accurate accusation. If you can call it that. I did look up which is also stated. I'm hoping that after all this time the bad day going on here is far addressed. I was a new dev, learned all of that on my own by using Bing, not Google, and again I had trouble searching for what I was being shown. John Gardner showed "how this works".

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code there is an example saying that if you do code like that (using `System.Diagnostic.Trace`) those messages *will end up in application insights* as trace messages there.

It is shown this way because this configuration (sending trace messages) is an optional step.